# How to open mail application window in xamarin ios application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I wan to open email by using open URL with mailto, subject and mail body text 
you can see the below code

```
string email = "me@example.com";
            string subject = "MySubject";
            string body = "Myboday";

            var idn = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping();
            var dotnetURI = new System.Uri("mailto:" + email + "?subject:" + subject + "&body:" + body);
            Console.WriteLine(dotnetURI.ToString());
            NSUrl nsURL = new NSUrl(dotnetURI.Scheme, idn.GetAscii(dotnetURI.DnsSafeHost), dotnetURI.PathAndQuery);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nsURL);
```

but I am getting error about absolute path

can you help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the string using the `NSString.CreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` method:

#### iOS Example:

```
string email = "me@example.com";
string subject = "Hello StackOverflow";
string body = "Happy Holdays";
using (var encoded = new NSString($"mailto:{email}?subject={subject}&body={body}").CreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NSStringEncoding.UTF8))
using (var url = NSUrl.FromString(encoded))
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
}
```

#### macOS Example:

```
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenUrl(url);
```

Note: Same code substituting `UIApplication.SharedApplication` with `NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace`